# Magento2 plugin around method different between callable and Closure paramters on param $proceed

Tags: magento2, plugin, object, parameter

I have checked magento2 ,There are two types of parameters that can be sent to

> around method
>
> - **`\Closure $proceed`** example `aroundSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, \closure $proceed)`
> - **`callable $proceed`** example `aroundSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, \callable $proceed)`

Now my question:

1. **What is different between closure and callable?**
2. **Why use we define type two different types for $proceed parameter?**
3. **What are use of this two types parameters?**

**Can any describe it details**

Comment: Nice question! Amit

Comment: could some one explain it again in simple terms? it will be very helpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730810/4629261

> The difference is, that a [`Closure`] must be an anonymous function, where [`callable`] also can be a normal function.
>
> You can see/test this with the example below and you will see that you will get an error for the first one:

```
function callFunc1(Closure $closure) {
    $closure();
}

function callFunc2(Callable $callback) {
    $callback();
}

function xy() {
    echo 'Hello, World!';
}

callFunc1("xy"); // Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to callFunc1() must be an instance of Closure, string given
callFunc2("xy"); // Hello, World!
```

> So if you only want to type hint anonymous function use: `Closure` and if you want also to allow normal functions use `callable` as type hint.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

In the Magento doc, they suggest to use [callable]

> Before the list of the original method’s arguments, around methods receive a callable that will allow a call to the next method in the chain. When the callable is called, the next plugin or the observed function is called.
>
> When you wrap a method which accepts arguments, your plugin must also accept those arguments and you must forward them when you invoke the proceed callable.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#defining-a-plugin

Comment: good, so what is best of use in around method to  magento?

Comment: I edited above, Magento suggest to use [callable]